# Hide or unhide one same series from all chart in worksheet using button

Tags: excel, vba, series

The purpose of the code is to hide/unhide the same series from all charts in the worksheet. if I input a certain number at one cell then I make a button to run the macro. Before it's working, but now it says there is "Run-time error '1004': Parameter not valid", the error is at line ``.FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = False". Also if a user input a wrong number (in this case more than 8), I intended to show a pop up message box, but how to make the message box disappear only with one OK click?. Some tips or help are much appreciated :)

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub UseValue()
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each ChObj In sht.ChartObjects
        With ChObj.Chart
        If Range("AE2").Value = 1 Then
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A2").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y2").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A3").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y3").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A4").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y4").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A5").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y5").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A6").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y6").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A8").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y8").IsFiltered = True
        ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 2 Then
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A3").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y3").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A4").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y4").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A5").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y5").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A6").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y6").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A8").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y8").IsFiltered = True
        ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 3 Then
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A4").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y4").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A5").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y5").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A6").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y6").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A8").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y8").IsFiltered = True
        ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 4 Then
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A4").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y4").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A5").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y5").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A6").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y6").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A8").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y8").IsFiltered = True
        ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 5 Then
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A4").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y4").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A5").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y5").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A6").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y6").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A8").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y8").IsFiltered = True
        ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 6 Then
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A4").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y4").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A5").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y5").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A6").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y6").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y7").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A8").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y8").IsFiltered = True
        ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 7 Then
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A4").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y4").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A5").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y5").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A6").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y6").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A7").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y7").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A8").IsFiltered = True
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y8").IsFiltered = True
        ElseIf Range("AE2").Value = 8 Then
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y1").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y2").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y3").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A4").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y4").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A5").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y5").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A6").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y6").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A7").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y7").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A8").IsFiltered = False
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y8").IsFiltered = False
        Else
            MsgBox ("Please input layer(s) from 1 to 8 !")
        End If
        End With
    Next ChObj
Next sht
```

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested the code with the assignment .FullSeriesCollection = 0!
Eventually you need to change the assignment from 0, 1, .. to False, True, ...

checked and corrected:
...
.FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(0) = 0
...

```
Public Sub UseValue()

Dim fsc(8) As Variant

fsc(1) = Split("0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1", ", ")
fsc(2) = Split("0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1", ", ")
fsc(3) = Split("0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1", ", ")
fsc(4) = Split("0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1", ", ")
fsc(5) = Split("0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1", ", ")
fsc(6) = Split("0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1", ", ")
fsc(7) = Split("0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1", ", ")
fsc(8) = Split("0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", ", ")

Dim actSel As Integer
actSel = Range("AE2").Value

If actSel < 1 Or actSel > 8 Then
    MsgBox ("Please input layer(s) from 1 to 8 !")
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim ChObj As ChartObject

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each ChObj In sht.ChartObjects
        With ChObj.Chart
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(0) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A2").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(1) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A3").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(2) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A4").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(3) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A5").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(4) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A6").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(5) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A7").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(6) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A8").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(7) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y1").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(8) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y2").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(9) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y3").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(10) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y4").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(11) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y5").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(12) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y6").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(13) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y7").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(14) = 0
            .FullSeriesCollection("Delta Y8").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(15) = 0
        End With
    Next ChObj
Next sht

End Sub
```

You might want to use the following code on the sheet where the Range("AE2") is. (Right Click on the sheet name => View Code) Then you don't need to press a button and the change of the charts is done immediately.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AE2")) Is Nothing Then
  'MsgBox ("You've changed the " & Target.Address & " address!")
  Call UseValue
 End If
End Sub
```

**Screenshot "Right Click on the sheet name => View Code"**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help :), I'll make sure to try again and send an update here!

Comment: Sorry for the late update, I have tried the code, but I got error at the ".FullSeriesCollection("Bottom A1").IsFiltered = fsc(actSel)(0) = 0". It said "Run-time error '1004': Parameter not valid". 

Do I miss something?